# I can't change my Apache2 web server Url from Localhost/192.168.0.xxx/127.0.0.1 to something like www.exaple.com

Tags: apache2, webserver, url

I'm runnig Apache2 webserver,but the only way I can access it is by tapping in in the server browser local host or 127.0.0.1 (or something like that) and 192.168.0.xxx on other devices connected to my home network. But I want to access it from outside of my local network and I can't. I found something called VirtualHost, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu is not about apache.

Comment: wow, but it is a program ON UBUNTU!!! so i'm asking

Comment: fufs: Sorry, but a program in Ubuntu that isn't really related to Ubuntu isn't accepted here.

Comment: The problem is with my computer not with program! My question is how to configure computer not apache!!!

Comment: It's just not related to Ubuntu, that's why we don't accept non-Ubuntu questions in Ask-Ubuntu. It's only for Ubuntu and help with Ubuntu (and etc.), not something like Apache.

Comment: Don't you understand. My problem is ubuntu not apache. That's why i'm asking for help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not purely Ubuntu related, and you may as well spend some time in Apache forums.

You seem to have several issues to solve:

- IP routing from outside network to your LAN-based server: this is a router related issue: have a look at port-forwarding and/or IP-forwarding features of your router.
- DNS : both locally (LAN) and outside! This issue has to be addresses in order to go beyond typing 192.168.0.xxx in your browser. If you don't have local DNS on your LAN, consider at 1rst step editing your /etc/hosts file on your client device.
- Apache2 itself: VirtualHost setup *is* the way to go, but after you adressed the two items above. Please see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: ok, 1. What port do I have to type when making port forwarding 2. Something more about the dns - what do you mean by saying : " If you don't have local DNS on your LAN, consider at 1rst step editing your /etc/hosts file on your client device."? 3. I said that Virtualhost setup doesn't work.

Comment: I'm new with ubuntu, so please precise your words.